# java api to get a file content for enterprise github

Tags: github, github-api, jcabi

I tried so hard for a simple line of code that read a file content from enterprise github with oauth token, but could not find a example of such.

I tried https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-github, but it does not support enterprise github?(maybe I am wrong)

Now i am trying egit:

```
GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient("enterprise url");

GitHubRequest request = new GitHubRequest();

request.setUri("/readme");

GitHubResponse response = client.get(request);
```

Then what? I only saw a getBody, maybe I need to parse it with some kinda json library? It has to be simpler..I am expecting something like: repo.get(url).getContent()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally figure out by reading source code..

```
    GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient(YOURENTERPRICEURL);
    client.setOAuth2Token(token);

    // first use token service
    RepositoryService repoService = new RepositoryService(client);

    try {
        Repository repo = repoService.getRepository(USER, REPONAME);

        // now contents service
        ContentsService contentService = new ContentsService(client);
        List<RepositoryContents> test = contentService.getContents(repo, YOURFILENAME);

        List<RepositoryContents> contentList = contentService.getContents(repo);
        for(RepositoryContents content : test){
            String fileConent = content.getContent();
            String valueDecoded= new String(Base64.decodeBase64(fileConent.getBytes() ));
            System.out.println(valueDecoded);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It is quite useful piece of code, in case some one want to stream the file from git repository instead of get the content. below code could do that: 

`List<RepositoryContents> contentList = contentService.getContents(repo);

for(RepositoryContents content : test){ 

String fileConent = content.getContent(); 

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(fileConent.getBytes())); }`